# Jquery Waypoints fadeIn and animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, fadein

I am currently working on a project that needs a few jquery functions which seem to be too complex to build for me, so I hope anyone here might have some solutions for me.

I am working on a one page scroll site and I already impleneted some functions using jquery and waypoints.

Here is the link to the current version of the project: http://art-design.de/onlineprospekt/demo/

If you scroll down a bit to the first big kitchen image, where you have a color change function underneath, you will recognize a mouse-cursor icon that starts to move up and down after you scroll to it. I created this function with waypoints with the following function:

JS:

```
<!--Moving finger waypoints start -->

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.finger_1').waypoint(function() {
        setInterval(function(){
            $('.finger_1').animate({ top: '-=12px' }, 500);
            $('.finger_1').animate({ top: '+=12px' }, 500);
        }, 1300);
    }, {offset: '70%',  triggerOnce: true });
});
</script>

<!--Moving fingers waypoints end -->
```

HTML

```
<img class="pageItem finger_1" src="assets/images/item_18171.png" alt="hand 1" style="left:239px;top:1410px;"/>
```

CSS

```
.pageItem {
box-sizing: border-box;
display: block;
height: auto !important;
width: auto !important;}
```

Now this kinda seems to work, but I am not satisfied with it, yet and I would like to add some more to this function. What I would like to achieve is, that the finger is not visible, but fades in after you scroll to that waypoint with offset '70%' and starts the animation from there as well.
As you can see, I somehow managed to get the animation to work, using some code that I found here on SO, but I am not satisfied yet and it looks like I can't get the fadein to work.

And in addition to all that, I need to do this do the same for all the finger images that are on the site if you scroll a bit further

```
<img class="pageItem finger_1" src="assets/images/item_18171.png" alt="hier klicken" style="left:239px;top:1410px;"/>
<img class="pageItem finger_2" src="assets/images/item_18171.png" alt="hier klicken" style="left:703px;top:1440px;"/>
<img class="pageItem finger_3" src="assets/images/item_18171.png" alt="hier klicken" style="left:408px;top:2641px;"/>
<img class="pageItem finger_4" src="assets/images/item_18171.png" alt="hier klicken" style="left:438px;top:3371px;"/>
<img class="pageItem finger_5" src="assets/images/item_18171.png" alt="hier klicken" style="left:643px;top:4433px;"/>
```

So there are five fingers that should be animated. How can I combine the function?
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

to combine the animation change

`class="pageItem finger_1"` to `class="pageItem finger finger_1"`

AND

`$('.finger_1')` to `$('.finger')`

For fadein effect you can try,

```
$('.finger').fadeOut();
$('.finger').waypoint(function() {
    $('.finger').fadeIn();
    setInterval(function(){
        $('.finger').animate({ top: '-=12px' }, 500);
        $('.finger').animate({ top: '+=12px' }, 500);
    }, 1300);
}, {offset: '70%',  triggerOnce: true });
```

**Update**

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('.finger').each(function(){
        $(this).waypoint(function() {
            $(this).fadeIn();
            setInterval(function(elem){
                elem.animate({ top: '-=12px' }, 500);
                elem.animate({ top: '+=12px' }, 500);
            }, 1300,$(this));
        }, {offset: "70%", triggerOnce: true }).fadeOut();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the effort. I updated the website with your code, but it looks like it is not working like I wanted it to be. Now it seems like the animation is fired for all fingers at the same time on document load, but not on the waypoint and I can't see and fade in.

Comment: do you mean `offset: '70%'` for each finger should be different?

Comment: fadeIn works locally for me, if you can't see this then change offset from `70%` to `72%` or `75%`.

Comment: Yes that would be the ultimate goal, to have the fingers fade in separately when each finger reaches for example the middle of the screen it fades in and animates.

Comment: thanks a lot. I will try it now and let you know if works. you are great help